# SharePoint 2013 ULS logs DistributedCacheService.exe

Tags: uls, distributedcache, logs

The ULS logs on the WFE server are filled with the following:

> 03/13/2018 09:59:45.62     DistributedCacheService.exe (0x0540)        0x3940  SharePoint Foundation           DistributedCache                ahlc3   Medium      Successfully executed... SPDistributedCacheClusterCustomProvider:: GetValue(object transactionContext, string type, string key).
>   03/13/2018 09:59:45.62  DistributedCacheService.exe (0x0540)        0x3940  SharePoint Foundation           DistributedCache                ahlcq   Medium      Calling... SPDistributedCacheClusterCustomProvider:: BeginTransaction
>   03/13/2018 09:59:45.62  DistributedCacheService.exe (0x0540)        0x3940  SharePoint Foundation           DistributedCache                ahlcr   Medium      Successfully executed... SPDistributedCacheClusterCustomProvider:: BeginTransaction

This is only occurring on one server. Any help?

Comment: It doesn't look like an error.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal logging behavior of DistributedCache Service in SharePoint 2013. Look here for an example on one of my farms:

[image: Distributed Cache Service log]

Answer (score 0):

It only shows up on one server as you probably run Distributed Cache from one server. The messages are normal behavior. You can check that by running those commands from PS window, it will list the servers that are part of the DistCache:

```
Use-cachecluster
Get-cachehost
```

Comment: I am running it on two servers, but this is only showing up on the one server. When I issue those commands, both servers show up

Comment: What load you have on the system. Maybe because of light load the second server is not utilized.